# What's wrong with my MAC address?

Tags: router, mac-address

I have a D-Link DSL-2650U router, and exactly one computer on the network.  For reasons of port forwarding I want to give my computer a static internal IP address, so that I don't take the chance of losing my NAT settings every time the computer reboots.

So here's a screen shot that summarizes the entire problem:

[image]

WTH is wrong with my MAC address?  It's copied and pasted from the command prompt window!  I tried editing out the dashes, but it still doesn't work.  Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in the D-Link firmware?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using : as the field delimiter instead of -

Comment: You genius, you!  :)

Comment: It was used as THE delimiter for a LONG time until MS decided to change things...